# Find acronyms in Haskell

Tags: beginner, strings, haskell

Related to [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/133721/generate-an-acronym) code golf challenge, I tried to find acronyms with Haskell without using regular expressions.

The idea is to split the input string at every space or dash before finally gluing the heads of these parts together, if they are uppercase.

This is my code:

```
import System.Environment
import Data.Char

main :: IO ()
main = do
    [inp] <- getArgs -- get input from the command line
    putStrLn $ getAcronym inp

getAcronym :: String -> String
getAcronym [] = []
getAcronym s  = foldr step [] parts
    where parts = split isWordSep s -- split into words
          step x acc = if isUpper . head $ x
                       then head x : acc else acc -- glue uppercase heads together

split :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
split p []       = []
split p s@(x:xs)
  | p x       = split p xs -- discard trailing white spaces
  | otherwise = w : split p r -- continue with the rest
      where (w, r) = break p s -- seperate prefix

isWordSep :: Char -> Bool
isWordSep x = x == ' ' || x == '-'
```

As this really seems like a very simple problem, my code looks like way too much complexity.

Do you have any helpful improvements to slim down my code?

Comment: `getAcronym = filter isUpper . map head . wordsBy isWordSep`, using `Data.List.Split`'s `wordsBy`.

Comment: That's a nice idea. I didn't know `wordsBy`.

Comment: @Erich keep in mind that `wordsBy` is from the package `split`. I'm not sure whether that is allowed on PCG.

Comment: @Zeta Me neither, but it doesn't really matter, as it was just for practicing purposes. On PCG I would use Regular Expressions anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of [Gurkenglas](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/84131/gurkenglas), I have found a good solution for this problem:

First, the `getAcronym` function can be dramatically reduced by using higher order functions and function composition:

```
getAcronym :: String -> String
getAcronym = filter isUpper . map head . split isWordSep
```

Second, the split function can be replaced with `Data.List.Split`'s `wordsBy` function, reducing the whole code to the following:

```
import System.Environment
import Data.Char
import Data.List.Split (wordsBy)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    [inp] <- getArgs -- get input from the command line
    putStrLn $ getAcronym inp

getAcronym :: String -> String
getAcronym = filter isUpper . map head . wordsBy isWordSep

isWordSep :: Char -> Bool
isWordSep x = x == ' ' || x == '-'
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you asked for help slimming down your code, I'll give you some hints that might otherwise be inadvisable.

1. Don't use `do`-notation. In fact, you can replace

   ```
   main :: IO ()
   main = do
       [inp] <- getArgs -- get input from the command line
       putStrLn $ getAcronym inp
   ```

   with

   ```
   main :: IO ()
   main = putStrLn =<< (fmap (getAcronym . head) getArgs)
   ```
2. I'd replace `isWordSep` to take advantage of pattern matching. As an example:

   ```
   isWordSep :: Char -> Bool
   isWordSep ' ' = True
   isWordSep '-' = True
   isWordSep _   = False
   ```
3. Consider using a parser library. Monadic parser combinators are quite nice, and they accomplish what you'd probably use regular expression for, but with far nicer error messages and type safety. Here's one example using [megaparsec](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/megaparsec-6.1.1):

   ```
   import           Control.Monad
   import           Data.Void
   import           Text.Megaparsec
   import           Text.Megaparsec.Char

   type Parser = Parsec Void String

   uppercaseWord :: Parser Char
   uppercaseWord = do
       h <- upperChar
       many $ noneOf "- "
       pure h

   acronymP :: Parser String
   acronymP = some $ do
       w <- uppercaseWord
       void (oneOf " -") <|> eof
       pure w

   acronym :: String -> IO ()
   acronym = parseTest acronymP
   ```

   You can unpack the `do`-notation to get:

   ```
   acronym :: String -> IO ()
   acronym = parseTest (acronymP :: Parser String)
       where
           acronymP = some (uppercaseWord >>= ((void (oneOf " -") <|> eof) >>) . pure)
           uppercaseWord = upperChar >>= ((many (noneOf "- ") >>) . pure)
   ```

   which, surprisingly enough, does indeed work.